# Mapping with key as Text is not working, but parsing it to Intwritable works

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm a beginner in hadoop and to learn i started doing outer join on two tables.
one has details about movies and other table has ratings.

sample data for movies table

```
movieId,title,genres
1,Toy Story (1995),Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy
2,Jumanji (1995),Adventure|Children|Fantasy
3,Grumpier Old Men (1995),Comedy|Romance
4,Waiting to Exhale (1995),Comedy|Drama|Romance
5,Father of the Bride Part II (1995),Comedy
6,Heat (1995),Action|Crime|Thriller
7,Sabrina (1995),Comedy|Romance
8,Tom and Huck (1995),Adventure|Children
9,Sudden Death (1995),Action
10,GoldenEye (1995),Action|Adventure|Thriller
```

sample data for ratings

```
userId,movieId,rating,timestamp
1,122,2.0,945544824
1,172,1.0,945544871
1,1221,5.0,945544788
1,1441,4.0,945544871
1,1609,3.0,945544824
1,1961,3.0,945544871
1,1972,1.0,945544871
2,441,2.0,1008942733
2,494,2.0,1008942733
2,1193,4.0,1008942667
2,1597,3.0,1008942773
2,1608,3.0,1008942733
2,1641,4.0,1008942733
```

MovieId is primary key in movies table and foreign key in ratings table.So used movieId as key in mapper class.I have used two mappers, one for movieId table and other for ratings table.

> code that i have written

```
public class Join {

public static class MovMapper
extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text>{
    private Text word = new Text();
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
            ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String[] arr= value.toString().split(",");
        word.set(arr[0]);
        //System.out.println(word.toString()+ " mov");
        context.write(word, value);
    }

}

public static class RatMapper
extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text>{
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
            ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String[] arr= value.toString().split(",");
        word.set(arr[1]);
        //System.out.println(word.toString() + " rat");
        context.write(word, value);
    }

}

public static class JoinReducer
extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text> {
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values,
            Context context
            ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        List <Text> rat=new ArrayList<Text>();
        Text mov= null;
        System.out.println("#######################################################################################");
        for(Text item:values){
            if(item.toString().split(",").length == 3){
                mov= new Text(item);
            }
            else
                rat.add(new Text(item));
                System.out.println("---->" + item);
        }
        System.out.println("item cnt: "+rat.size()+" mov"+mov+" key"+key+" byte: "+key.getBytes().toString());
        for(Text item:rat){
            if(mov != null) {
                context.write(item,mov);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("#######################################################################################");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "join");
    job.setJarByClass(Join.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(JoinReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(JoinReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]),TextInputFormat.class,MovMapper.class);
    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]),TextInputFormat.class,RatMapper.class);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

**Problem**

*While mapping,records from movies table and ratings table are getting mapped to different tasks though the movieId is same.surprisingly when i convert movieId into intwritable, records from both tables matching with the key are getting mapped to same task.*

Comment: It isn't very clear from your problem statement what the actual issue is. Can you elaborate perhaps? As i understand it you seem to have posted code that works, rather than the version you're having problems with.

Comment: code isn't working, this is the code im working on.If i change the key to intwritable in mapper, code works.

Comment: Having a combiner seems a bit odd. I would remove that to start with.

Comment: that worked, but why combiner seems odd to you?

Comment: You're trying to do a reduce side join, i can imagine having a combiner in some situations like this, but it wouldnt usually be the same code as the reducer, which is what your trying to do. Since the combiner is (basically) running on the mappers output, how would it be able to join anything? I bet you would find if you looked at your counters, you weren't getting any records entering your reducers.